# How to code the "X" close button for a wordpress element

Tags: html, wordpress, notifications

I want to create a custom "X" close or hide button, image, text that works for a complete element box in wordpress. I've attached a sample image of the "x" on something else. For my site however I need it to control the whole element or (tiles) on my [page](http://optionalpha.com/new-dashboard) not just the single box of text.

Sample [image](http://jquery-plugins.net/image/plugin/toastr-simple-javascript-toast-notifications.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a easy task for you, basically on this situation what you have to do is create the "x" graphic with any iconfont or  you can use the "X" from any font(like a regular x that you just have to touch your keyboard) then what you have to do is follow this example.

HTML

```
<div class="yourbox"> 
<!--- THIS IS THE BOX THAT YOU WANT TO CLOSE, you can use id or clas whatever you want-->
<p> text or content of the box <p>
<a id="close"href=""> X </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.yourbox{
height:100px;
width:400px;
background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#close").click(function () {
    $( "#yourbox" ).css( "display", "none" );

  });
});    
</script>
```

You could name the function as you want, use class instead of id and basically the code will hie the div after you touch the " X ".